# How can I avoid using *ngIf in an Angular template?

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-ng-if

I tried using async/await to avoid `*ngIf` in the component template.

I'm getting an error in the Chrome console when I remove `*ngIf` in component template.

Can anyone help to get a solution. I do not want to use `*ngIf` in the component template as a requirement

I'm calling the GET REST API and used subscribe. Also, I'm getting results without the error if I'm using `*ngIf`, but I want the same results without using `*ngIf`

**CODE:**
component.ts

```
export class DisplayComponent implements OnInit {
users : user[];
user: user;
userResult: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  async readUser(id){
     this.userResult = await this.http.get<user>("http://localhost:8090/user/" +id).subscribe(
       data => {
         this.user = data;
       },
       error =>{
         return console.error();
         ;
       }
     )
    console.log("Fuuhhh! Client will wait till promise is resolved.");
  }
}
```

**CODE:** DisplayComponent.html

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <button (click)="loadUsers()">load Users</button>
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Identity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
           <td>
            <button style="background: transparent;border: transparent;cursor: pointer;" (click)="readUser(user.id)">{{user?.id}}</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="color: darkgray;">Identity:</span> <span style="color: gray;">{{user.id}}</span> <br>
    <span>Name:</span> {{user.name}} <br> 
    <span>School:</span> {{user.school}} <br> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code and the error message.

Comment: Sure just a minute.

Comment: I dont see you using *ngIf in the template

Comment: @DanielF Please check the code in Question.

Comment: Where is ngIf??

Comment: @ShijilNarayanan Yes that only, I have mentioned in Question clearly. I don't want to use *ngIf in template, So I want something to avoid *ngIf (because this is just minor code part, in template I have used *ngIf more than 10 times, So I want some alternative of *ngIf)

Comment: You say you dont want to use ngIf and the code you shared already dont have ngIf in place, I am confused.

Comment: @GaganDeep Yes that only, I have mentioned in Question clearly. I don't want to use *ngIf in template, So I want something to avoid *ngIf (because this is just minor code part, in template I have used *ngIf more than 10 times, So I want some alternative of *ngIf)

Comment: @ShijilNarayanan Can you help me providing some alternative

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to show clicked users information only when the `this.user` has the selected user value ?

Comment: @ShijilNarayananYes I just want to show users information in div but yes without using *ngIf Thanks

Comment: Could you give us a hint where you are currently forced to put the `*ngIf` attributes?

Comment: @DanielF Actually my Manager wants way from my side to write code avoiding *ngIf in any case!

Comment: So I have a searched a lot and last posted on StackOverflow

Comment: @ChintanRaval I meant where in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Folks for trying to help me out in different ways. But yes I didn't get a resolution from the answers.

Finally, I got the solution myself doing some R&D on "avoiding *ngIf", and following is the in-short solution:

**Using Angular "Resolver" service I got the data before rendering the template/View.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the ngIf because, your template loads before it gets your data.
So your HTML is prepared to get the data. What you can do, and its more clean, is to create a boolean var:

```
isDataReady: Boolean = false;
```

Then in your html just use it because it will always be false until you change it in your component when the subscription gets the data.

Also, in my projects i use an angular material spinner, to let the user know its loading the back end data with this variable i created.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually yes are correct that template loads before getting data form the Server. If I am not using *ngIf than I m getting Error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]"  >>>>So I m trying not to use *ngIf and I error can get resolved. *POINT IS I have so many templates, So I cannot waste time just adding *ngIf everywhere. This is the thing. Thanks

Comment: you can just wrap everything that will contain api data in a big div with the conditional and it will be just an ngif

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the *ngIf in the right way.All you need to do is add a *ngIf in your template as following, you dont need to add multiple *ngIf for every tags.

```
<div style="text-align: center;" *ngIf="user">
    <span style="color: darkgray;">Identity:</span> <span style="color: gray;">{{user.id}}</span> <br>
    <span>Name:</span> {{user.name}} <br> 
    <span>School:</span> {{user.school}} <br> 
</div>
```

Comment: I know *ngIf will show the users information. But this is just a small block of HTML & I have many blocks many!, So my point for this Question is finding a way to avoid *ngIf and I can show the users information also without using *ngIf!

Comment: There is no harm in using *ngif in your template as and when required, its purpose is to show and hide information only conditionally, and its the cleanest way to hide or show things within template when it comes to Angular

Comment: Shijil Narayan Yes you are correct! But If u can help me finding alternative way

Comment: There are many dirty ways to do it, like using css display none on your html and set it to display block within typescript when you get the user object from backend, but i will never recommend you to do that

Answer (score 0):

Angular have a lifecycle system, so Angular is trying to load the component before getting the data from your API. So yes, you need to handle the case before the API responds.

You have 2 ways to do that :

- use *ngIf but you don't have to use *ngIf everywhere if you make many calls if this is your fear, you can use ngrx properly and use one *ngIf only in your HTML
- initialize your data with default value. Angular will load your "default" user and replace it by the user received by the API, if there is no error of course. If you really want to use that, try a

```html
user: user = new user();
```

and of course, initiliaze all the attribute you are using by empty string, ... in the user constructor.

But I think the first way is better because you can handle the error and the waiting case more properly with a loading spinner, loading and error message, ... BUT you need to learn basics of rxjs :)

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have for storing the userResult is not a promise, is a subscription:

```js
async readUser(id){
     // this block is wrong, userResult is a subscription
     this.userResult = await this.http.get<user>("http://localhost:8090/user/" +id).subscribe(
       data => {
         this.user = data;
       },
       error =>{
         return console.error();
         ;
       }
     )
    console.log("Fuuhhh! Client will wait till promise is resolved.");
  }
```

If you want to use promises (but you should you observables in Angular) you can do it using `toPromise()` method like this:

```js
async readUser(id){
     try {
       this.userResult = await this.http.get<user>("http://localhost:8090/user/" +id).toPromise();
       this.user = this.userResult // if you really want an extra step here
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Regarding your question, you should use `*ngIf` for this case.

For blocks of code use it with `ng-container` like so:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="user">
   .....
</ng-container>
```